# Meaning of "a good set of"

Tags: meaning

> You are blessed if you have a good set of friends.

Apparently "you have a good set of friends" can have two readings:

> (1) you have numerous friends

> (2) you have many friends such that all of the friends are ***good***

Which one is correct?

Comment: Is there any more context for the original sentence? The use of 'blessed' suggests goodness but it's not a certainty based on the sentence alone.

Comment: Many sentences containing "a good set of" can be found on Internet. Is this construction inherently polysemous?

Comment: Hello, thatness. Could you add dictionary definitions showing that 'good' itself is indeed polysemous? [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good) perhaps goes overboard here. It might be difficult to find dictionary definitions for the whole expression. Sometimes the set is well-defined, forcing the 'good quality' sense ('a good set of darts / chessmen // lungs //  ...'). Sometimes, still ambiguous ('a good set of pans / knives // young players // ...').

Comment: I'll convert the above comment to an answer if OP shows research, though I doubt I'll find authoritative confirmation.

Comment: Yes, it's inherently ambiguous. _A good set_ can refer to the size of a set, or to its 'goodness of fit', i.e, quality in whatever purpose the set is mentioned for. Mind you, **all** English sentences are multiply ambiguous in print, since intonation is not represented in writing. But this is ambiguous even in speech.

Comment: In Case you want to state that the Set is good : use "a good set of friends". In Case you want to state that the friends are good : use "a set of good friends". It is ambiguous when we state "a good friend set" : hence try to avoid using that.

Comment: I can but wonder what "correct" means.

Comment: It's like having a good set of golf clubs.

Comment: If only one is correct (as you seem to expect), then the phrase can't legitimately have two readings, yet you suggest that it can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> Yes, it's inherently ambiguous. *A good set* can refer to the size of a set, or to its 'goodness of fit', i.e, quality in whatever purpose the set is mentioned for. Mind you, **all** English sentences are multiply ambiguous in print, since intonation is not represented in writing. But this is ambiguous even in speech.